How to disable tmux prefix
I want to make it so when I press CTRL+Shift+T it opens a new window (the current CTRL+B, C) in tmux. I don't want to have to press CTRL+B (or any other prefix keybind). If I set -g prefix None it will disable all keyboard shortcuts, which is not what I want either. How can I disable the requirement for a prefix without disabling all keyboard shortcuts altogether.

Possible problem: AFAIK there is no standard character or sequence for Ctrl+Shift+T in a terminal. Upon Ctrl+Shift+T you will probably get ^T, i.e. the same character as for Ctrl+T, unless you configure your terminal emulator to generate a custom escape sequence. Then you configure tmux to expect this sequence.
